# CakePHP Saving HasMany through if it doesn't exist yet

Tags: php, database, cakephp

I was wondering whether there's a possibility to easily achieve the following in CakePHP:

I've got three Models. *Recipes*, *Ingredients* and *RecipeIngredients*. One Recipe can have many *Ingredients*, the relation is saved through the Model *RecipeIngredients* therefore we have a HasMany through relationship.

Now, when adding a new Recipe, I have multiple Ingredients, which can easily be saved with  `$this->Recipe->saveAssociated();` - as long as I already know the foreignKey of the Ingredient.

Nevertheless, as there can be countless Ingredients, it's impossible to fill them all in a `<select>` field or anything similar. Therefore I want the User to fill out a field with `$this->Recipe->RecipeIngredient->Ingredient['title']` and check the database against an existing entry with the title, if yes, get the id and fill it in the *RecipeIngredients* table, otherwise create a new Ingredient and save that id into *RecipeIngredients*

Usually CakePHP is full of shortcuts, but in this case I couldn't find anything, but maybe there's an easy solution which I overlooked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you can do is to create a `beforeSave` function in your model. If the `POST'ed` data for the ingredient allready exists (you could do a find where in the options LIKE is `Ingredient['title']`) grab the ID and store that in the POST'ed array. If there is not yet such an ingredient in your database, store it directly, grab the saved ID and store that in your POST'ed array.